# Combining coffeescript with requirejs

Tags: coffeescript, requirejs

What is the best way to combine coffeescript with requirejs ?
I am confused with coffeescript self invoking function - by default all properties are not visible outside of that function (after compiling ). If I do something like this with requirejs using coffee:

```
// requirejs module
define=(do()->
    this.app = 
        someproperty: "property" // export to global scope
)
```

Then app object will be globally accessible, and not just inside main require module.

So trying to access app object inside of main require module will fail:

```
require("modules/modulename",function(name){
    name.app.some // this will fail
    this.app.someproperty // this works but it is global
})
```

How to make module created with coffeescript visible only inside requirejs main script ?

Thanks

Comment: Rather than editing your question and putting [SOLVED] in the title, you should post your resolution as an answer to your question, and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved** with the help of [An AMD loader plugin for CoffeeScript](https://github.com/jrburke/require-cs)